# Sum of an Array, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok so I'm working on a lab assignment for school in which we have to generate 10 random numbers. The code I have so far does that. But for the second part we have to have it display the sum of those numbers using document.write or any other display method, and I am pretty stumped.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Lab 5 </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var numbers = new Array(10);
var sum = 0;
var i;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
document.write("numbers[" + i + "]: " + Math.floor(Math.random() *100)+ "<br/>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're looping but you're not incrementing the `sum`.

Comment: You are never adding any values to your `numbers` array. Just pointing it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a trivial error. Too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit things a bit. 
You need to create a `random_number` variable and assign the random figure, so that you can output that value and add it to the sum.

Hope it helps!

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Lab 5 </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var numbers = new Array(10);
var sum = 0;
var i;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() *100);
    document.write("numbers[" + i + "]: " + random_number + "<br/>");
    sum += random_number;
}
document.write("Total: " + sum);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does he need a total variable if he already has sum?

Comment: @user2532739 you're absolutely right! Had missed that!

Comment: gotcha! thanks again, noob here haha

Comment: haha. no problem. I'm new as well. take care!

Answer (score 1):

Create a current number variable and then set it equal to your random number in each iteration of your for loop. Then all you have to do is add it to your sum and display it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are never storing the numbers in the array, and not really adding. (Assuming that you've been asked to store these numbers) the correct loop would be as follows:

```
var numbers = [];
var sum = 0;
var randomNumber;

for(var i = 0;i<10;i++){
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  numbers.push(randomNumber);
  sum += randomNumber;
  document.write("numbers[" + i + "] = " + randomNumber + "<br/>");
}
document.write("sum = " + sum);
```